# What is calculated KPI

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, business-intelligence

What is calculated KPI? I am not looking for "how to create it" but rather its concept. What exactly it is? How do you define calculated KPI if someone asks?

Answer (score 0):

KPI, or key performance indicators, are measurements used by a business to track company performance against its specific objectives. Every KPI has either a specific target or a range in which the score must fall in for the company to successfully meet its goals. KPIs vary depending on the particular business and the performance indicators they aim to measure.

refer below links More details.....

http://www.ehow.com/how_5875354_calculate-kpi.html
http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/dmndhelp/v6rxmx/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.btools.help.modeler602.doc/doc/concepts/measures/kpis.html